# Going in circles trying to log in to AWS certification

Tags: windows, login, website

I'm trying to log in to [AWS certification](https://www.aws.training/SignIn) as preparation for an upcoming exam. My preferred operating system is Linux, where I can login without issues. The exam however requires me to run Windows or Mac OS. I found a laptop, which I use for testing, where Windows is running, but all attempts so far have been unsuccessful. No error message is provided and it doesn't matter which browser I use or if I reset the cache. I'm always referred back to the login page.

Answer (score 1):

## That bug with (dual-)booting Windows and time...

Check that the **time matches your time-zone**. If not disable and re-enable network time source in the settings, so that the computer syncs time. You should be able to login now.

There is no error message. I found no article yet which suggests how to solve this issue. It's a known issue where Windows behaves different than most other operating systems on the same platform and you can configure Linux and Windows appropriately (unless you are running certain live media), but I thought I'd share it somewhere so that someone in the same situation saves a bit of time and stress to figure this out.

## Also good to know...

When you use Android and you prefer another browser than Chrome and thus have disabled Chrome you should re-enable it for the check in process of the exam. Check how to do that while you have to save yourself some stress.